# Cross-login and parsing user specific data

Tags: php, android

I want to develop an application for a website which provides user specific information. These user specific information of course are just visible as long as you're logged-in. Json-interface and parser will be hosted on a different server and I'm wondering how to handle the login + maintain a session in order to parse the data. The loginscript of the website which I want to parse is using POST and puts a cookie with username + md5 password.

These are all information I can provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the android app send the user login info, on the server side check to make sure the user name and password is correct.  If it is send back a cookie in the response.  Store the Cookie in your `SharedPreferences`'s or some other storing mechanism.  Along with every web request there after you can send along that cookie and make sure they are authorized and send back the user specif information requested.

Comment: Well this would mean my server has to log in on the source website for every single request. 'Cause the Cooky on my server might be overwritten by a new client connection who also wants to get his data parsed. I was just hoping that I could handle multiple sessions on my server, so that the clients who already logged in don't have to re-login every time. Sure I could store it in a Cooky on the cellphone but my server would have to re-login on the source website every time cause it can only handle on session at a time..